# How can I check hash generated Cryptonight before to send?

Tags: c#, hash

I have made a miner with C# language for make BCN, XMR and it works with all Pools.

But I want to check my hash generated with my code with the target received from the Pool.

I have made something like that:

```
      public bool CheckHash(byte[] hash, byte[] target)
      {
        for (int i = 0; i < target.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int k = hash.Length-1; k >= 0; k--)
            {
                Log("test de: " + (hash[k] & 0x20));
                if ((hash[k] & 0x20) > (target[i] & 0x04))
                {
                    Log("Hash invalid: " + _cryptonightLib.ToHexString(hash));
                    return false;
                }
                if ((hash[k] & 0x20) < (target[i] & 0x04))
                {
                    Log("Hash is valid: " + _cryptonightLib.ToHexString(hash));
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        Log("Hash invalid: "+_cryptonightLib.ToHexString(hash));
        return false;
     }
```

But that does not really work.

Example origin hash received on the miner: 0505efcfdccb0506180897d587b02f9c97037e66ea638990b2b3a0efab7bab0bff4e3f3dfe1c7d00000000a6788e66eb9b82325f95fc7a2007d3fed7152a3590366cc2a9577dcadf3544a804

Example hash generated and successfully send by the miner: 960A7A3A1826B0AA70E8043FFE7B9E23EE2E028BBA75F3D7557CCDFF9C7F1A00

Example target: e4a63d00

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I will try to show how the algorithm works by using JavaScript examples. I am pretty new to CryptoNight, but I try my best:

Your example hash actually are two hashes, each 32 characters long.

```
var hash1 = '960A7A3A1826B0AA70E8043FFE7B9E23EE2E028BBA75F3D7557CCDFF9C7F1A00'
    .slice(0, 32);

var hash2 = '960A7A3A1826B0AA70E8043FFE7B9E23EE2E028BBA75F3D7557CCDFF9C7F1A00'
    .slice(-32);
```

Then to find out what each of this hash has "reached", you need to take the last 8 characters and convert it into an integer

```
var reached1 = parseInt(hash1.slice(24), 16)
var reached2 = parseInt(hash2.slice(24), 16)
```

Now you can just compare it with the target:

```
parseInt(reached1, 16) < parseInt("e4a63d00", 16)
    -> false
parseInt(reached2, 16) < parseInt("e4a63d00", 16)
    -> true
```